# Finding the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the following tridiagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have run into the following n by n tridiagonal matrix and I am confused on how to find a closed form solution for the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of this matrix.

$A = \begin{pmatrix}
\Delta_1 & 1 & 0 &... & 0\\
1 & \Delta_2 & 1 &...&0\\
0 & 1 & \Delta_3 & ...& 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
0 & 0 & \dots & 1 & \Delta_n 
\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: Have you tried finding a recursion relation between the characteristic polynomials? Also what is $\Delta_i$?

Comment: @julio_es_sui_glace The $\Delta_i$'s are just various constants that are all different from each other. How would I go about finding a recursive relation among them?

Comment: Develop the determinant using basic rules, you will find a recursion relation of order two, this is a tridiagonal matrix. With it you could deduce the result of @DimitriZvonkine. But you won't find a useful closed form if your constants are not specific

Answer (score 3):

There is no closed form in general. One potentially useful thing to know is that the determinant of this matrix is equal to the numerator of the continued fraction
$$
\Delta_1 - \frac1{\Delta_2 - \frac1{\dots - \frac1{\Delta_n}}}.
$$
Thus $x$ is an eigenvalue iff
$$
(\Delta_1-x) - \frac1{(\Delta_2-x) - \frac1{\dots - \frac1{(\Delta_n-x)}}} = 0.
$$